# Panic when querying the chaincode to fabric-sdk-go

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I'm trying to figure out how fabric-sdk-go works.
I created a connection with hyperledger, installed chaincode, but when I try to execute the request for some reason I get an error.

My function:

```
response, err := setup.client.Query(channel.Request{ChaincodeID: setup.ChainCodeID, Fcn: "invoke", Args: [][]byte{[]byte("query"), []byte("hello")}})
```

And the output log:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x9384f0]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/channel.(*Client).Query(0x0, 0xce8db5, 0x5, 0xce9c7d, 0x6, 0xc0001b1bd0, 0x3, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /home/batazor/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.12/global/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go@v1.0.0-alpha5/pkg/client/channel/chclient.go:97 +0xc0
main.(*FabricSetup).QueryHello(0xc000171eb0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x28, 0xc0001b0460)
        /home/batazor/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.12/global/src/github.com/batazor/hyperledger-fabric/cmd/hyperledger-fabric/example.go:10 +0x217
main.main()
        /home/batazor/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.12/global/src/github.com/batazor/hyperledger-fabric/cmd/hyperledger-fabric/main.go:43 +0x143
```

P.S. My chaincode -> https://github.com/batazor/hyperledger-fabric/blob/master/chaincode/hello/go/hello.go

Comment: Can you add some part of chaincode too?

Comment: @bibek-koirala add a link to chaincode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I skipped the channel connection setup step

[image]

https://github.com/chainHero/heroes-service/blob/master/blockchain/setup.go#L93-L136